# Calculate monthly sum from SQL table (Laravel)

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a SQL table with some data like the below image. I want to calculate the monthly total value with that month number. How can I do with Laravel DB queries? Actually, I want the result as an array to display in a Pie chart. How can I get an array with monthly sum & month numbers?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
TableName::select(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') as month"), DB::raw("sum(value) as value")
         ->groupBy("month")->get();
```

Comment: @B001ᛦ there is an alias 'month' created by this part `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') as month` and I'm using the alias in the `groupBy`, which is allowed in MySQL.

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer working with collections instead. Provided that you cast the date column as a date in your model, you could do like this:

```php
$items = Item::whereYear('date', '2021')->get()->groupBy(function ($item) {
    return $item->date->month;
})->map(function ($item) {
    return $item->sum('value');
});
return $items;
```

If you prefer using DB facade

```php
$items = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('items')->get()->groupBy(function ($item) {
    return \Illuminate\Support\Carbon::parse($item->date)->month;
})->map(function ($item) {
    return $item->sum('value');
});
return $items;
```

You end up with a collection in the end anyway.

Comment: I'm only using Laravel DB queries, can you give solution from that..I'm new to Laravel framework. thank yoy